# cameraoverlayview not transformed in updated version ios4.3

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I designed a small camera application, in which I rotated and translated camera overlayview in order to fix in desired position, it worked fine ,
[image]

when i updated to ios 4.3 it didnt worked, initially, it displays transformed view after few seconds the view changed to portrait .
[image]

I did not understand what went wrong.., Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this with my app as well. Seems like the cameraOverlayView in iOS 4.3 is assumed to be the size of the screen e.g 320x480. See this post for an explanation for a similar problem I think you're experiencing. [iOS 4.3 changed transformation on UIImagePickerController's camera overlay view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336318/ios-4-3-changed-transformation-on-uiimagepickercontrollers-camera-overlay-view)