# iOS 4.3 changed transformation on UIImagePickerController's camera overlay view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, ios4

After testing my App on iOS 4.3 I noticed that the camera overlay of my UIImagePickerController has an added transformation that stretched the content extremely. Pre iOS 4.3 everything shows up correctly.

Here is what I do

```
imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

cameraOverlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
cameraOverlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cameraOverlay.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

//add subviews to camera Overlay

imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = pauseButton;
```

Any ideas what I have to do to get rid of the added transformation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK found the answer. ios 4.3 requires to have the camerOverlay as big as the screen is. So my 200x200 camera overlay was enlarged.

If I change the line:

```
cameraOverlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
```

to

```
cameraOverlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
```

it works :).