# cameraOverlayView problem on iOS 4.3

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller, ios4

I'm using an picker Controller with a cameraOverlayView to display an image of a product in the camera view. The product image is resized before applying on the overlay. 
It works fine on iOS 4.2 but on iOS 4.3 the product image is displayed full size.

```
pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
UIImageView *imgView =  [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:produitAffiche.img_realite]] autorelease];

// Resize
if(imgView.frame.size.height == 480)
{
    //Portrait
    imgView.frame = CGRectMake(80.0f, 120.0f, 160.0f, 240.0f);
}
else
{
    // Landscape
    imgView.frame = CGRectMake(40.0f, 160.0f, 240.0f, 160.0f);
}

imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
imgView.clipsToBounds = NO;
imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;  

pickerController.cameraOverlayView = (UIView *) imgView;
```

I changed the frame of the UIImageView I use as overlay but it's still displayed at 320*480.
I know that the cameraOverlayView have been modified in iOS 4.3 but I don't know what has changed and what I have to do to correct my application.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I had the same issue. Found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336318/ios-4-3-changed-transformation-on-uiimagepickercontrollers-camera-overlay-view)

Comment: The linked answer doesn't really help; it just says to make your view larger. How can we still work with a view that is smaller than the full window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS 4.3 the overlay view is stretched to full screen. Because you set the content mode to aspect fit, the image is stretched to fit the new view size which is 320x480.

You need to make a transparent UIView that is fullscreen, add the imageview to that view and make the UIView the new overlay view.

```
UIView *fullscreenView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
fullscreenView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
....
 [fullscreenView addSubview:imgView];
pickerController.cameraOverlayView = fullscreenView;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found [this article](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/) that seems to fit the bill.  The long and short of it is to use

```
- (UIImage *)
  resizedImageWithContentMode:(UIViewContentMode)contentMode
                       bounds:(CGSize)bounds
         interpolationQuality:(CGInterpolationQuality)quality;
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment out this line in your code

> `imgView.clipsToBounds = NO;`

It should work.
If you really want to clip, @slf 's answer should help.

Answer (score 0):

try setting these properties of `UIImagePicker`:

```
mImagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;

mImagePickerController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

mImagePickerController.toolbarHidden = YES;

mImagePickerController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was actually that a UIImagePicker displayed full-screen on iOS5 did not work on iOS4.3, on an iPad.  I was starting the image picker up offscreen, then animating it into view...  You would see the shutter image open up, but then the camera view itself was simply transparent with no camera output.

My solution was to not animate that in for iOS4.3 on the iPad.  It seems that having the camera view started offscreen was leaving the camera rendering part behind (fixed as I noted in iOS5).

This answer is not quite right for the original question but I place it here for someone that comes into the same issue and hits this question as I did.