# transparency in UIImagePickerController cameraOverlayView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

[Several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952492/cameraoverlayview-problem-on-ios-4-3) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321374/cameraoverlayview-not-transformed-in-updated-version-ios4-3) [discuss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336318/ios-4-3-changed-transformation-on-uiimagepickercontrollers-camera-overlay-view) how in iOS 4.3, the cameraOverlayView of a UIImagePickerController is scaled to the size of the screen. I am trying to implement a custom set of controls for one of these controllers, and so now as I cannot have the overlayView have a smaller frame and be positioned at the bottom, I'm trying to use transparency.

My question is, if I have a full-screen view with alpha=0.5, is there some way to have a subview of it have a *greater* alpha? If so I can make the bulk of the cameraOverlayView be transparent. Otherwise I don't know how to make a useful overlayView.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a start. If I set the frame of the overlayView *after* calling presentModalViewController then it correctly fills up only part of the screen.